# Javascript not populating fields on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following form which I want to populate with values for `input` and `textarea`

```
<form id="message-form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id">
    <textarea id="message" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
    <button class="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

I made the following function which doesn't seem to work as I expect. I initiate the function using `initMessageForm(1,'Name')`:

```
function initMessageForm(user_id, name){
    console.log('Clicked on Send Message Button');
    var form = document.getElementById('message-form');
    form.getElementById('user_id').value = user_id;
    form.getElementById('message').placeholder = 'Your Message to ' + name;
}
```

The final output should be:

```
<form id="message-form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="1">
    <textarea id="message" cols="40" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message to Name"></textarea>
    <button class="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form.getElementById` is not a valid function. You should use `document.getElementById` instead:

```js
function initMessageForm(user_id, name) {
  var form = document.getElementById('message-form');
  document.getElementById('user_id').value = user_id;
  document.getElementById('message').placeholder = 'Your Message to ' + name;
}

initMessageForm('1', 'Name');
```

```html
<form id="message-form" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id">
  <textarea id="message" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
  <button class="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @AtulSharma -- Please read OP's function and the expected result. OP clearly states that _I want to populate with value_.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select form elements from it by it's id. You can select them from the `document` context. But if you want to select them by using the `form` element, then you can use named property:

```
function initMessageForm(user_id, name){
    console.log('Clicked on Send Message Button');
    var form = document.getElementById('message-form');
    form.user_id.value = user_id;
    form.message.placeholder = 'Your Message to ' + name;
}
initMessageForm(1,'Name')
```

Where you should have name attribute on your form elements:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id">
<textarea id="message" name="message" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
```